# How to convert an object into an array in AngularJS directive

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is some code in directive to get pagination

```
scope.pagingOptions = {
               pageSizes: [5, 10, 15,],
               pageSize: 5,
               currentPage: 1
                     };
              scope.filterOptions = {
                 filterText: "",
                 useExternalFilter: true
                    }; 
                 scope.totalServerItems = 0;
         scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){  

                $rootScope.griddata =scope.griddata;

                var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
                   scope.griddata = pagedData;

                  scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
                        if (!scope.$$phase) {
                             scope.$apply();
                                }
                                };
                scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                 var data;
                   if (searchText) {
                      var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                                 } else {

                            scope.setPagingData($rootScope.myData,page,pageSize);
                                     }
                                   }, 500);
                                };

                                        scope.getPagedDataAsync(scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

                        scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {

                      if (newVal !== oldVal ) {
                                                          scope.getPagedDataAsync(scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, scope.filterOptions.filterText);
                                        }
                                    }, true);
                    scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {

                    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                                                          scope.getPagedDataAsync(scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, scope.filterOptions.filterText);
                                        }
                                        }, true);

                                  },500);
```

the code in the controller

```
$rootScope.myData = bankService
                    .getWorkItemsByBank($rootScope.selectedBankName);
```

In the controller I am hitting the db and getting the result in  $rootScope.myData variable and in my directive I am using this same variable to pass into the method "setPagingData" but I am getting undefined in not a function at the below line

```
data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
```

The result stored in $rootScope.myData is as below

```
 {"$$v":[{"Number":"35973","id":"09510uiy8240E","ItemType":"Application", "amount":"USD","aWorker":"WorkerAMS1","aWorkGroupType":"Unassigned","receiptDate":"2008-12-04","receiptTime":"","curTrkStatuses":"REL, CMP"},{"Number":"35973","id":"09510uiy8240E","ItemType":"Application", "amount":"USD","aWorker":"WorkerAMS1","aWorkGroupType":"Unassigned","receiptDate":"2008-12-04","receiptTime":"","curTrkStatuses":"REL, CMP"}]}
```

I thought the value above is an object but the data.slice method works for array and also tried to convert an object to array that is also didnt work.so please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: Your JSON contains an array of 1 sub-document. You should be able to access it using $rootScope.myData.$$v. Paging on 1 element isn't all that interesting though.

Comment: Yes tried that too but its working for the first time and when I hit db with different value its returning empty values.

Comment: Then the issue is probably that you're either sending a wrong value (or one that your DB doesn't understand) or that your DB doesn't have any result. Try using the console (F12 usually) to see what kind of messages are passing by.

Comment: yes I have assigned the value to another rootscope variable now its working thanks.